# Video Streaming Platform using Google Drive (PHP)

Tags: php, google-drive-api, video-streaming, google-drive-android-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I am trying to develop a video sharing platform based on PHP, using Google Drive as video hosting media.

Basically, my system will have multiple users and they will be able to upload videos from dashboard and if user wants he can change permission(public/private) for other users to view/block the videos on website (Android app in future).

Now my questions regarding Google Drive are:

1. Is it possible to create folders for each user and give user access to that folder only?
2. Is it possible to upload videos to single google drive account?
3. Is it possible to manage permission(public/private) to each videos uploaded in google drive?
4. Is it possible to embed video which should not be downloadable?

Comment: Is it possible that you share what you have tried first? There's a [PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/php) that you can try right away.

Comment: actually i haven't started coding for google drive yet. i just wanted to be sure if the features are possible with google drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers:

1. yes, you can create unlimited folder for each user but you must save folder ID for each user in database.
2. yes, free user limit 15Gb, buy extra space like 100GB, 1TB or more.
3. yes, default permission is Private but you can change it by Google Drive ApI.
4. yes, google drive allow embed video.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Can you provide some reference link.